# File created and opened with Streamwriter vanishes when end using is hit

Tags: vb.net, streamwriter

The following code, in a Console app

```
        Using (System.IO.File.Create(Path & "\" & file))
        End Using
        Using FSW As New System.IO.StreamWriter(Path & "\" & file, False)
            FSW.WriteLine(header)
```

creates a file and opens it to write with streamwriter.  I don't think I actually need to create the file first.  I think that the opening for reading would do that for me.  The Console app does some stuff and then closes/disposes of the stream writer with an end using.  A couple of things:

1. This code is being called inside a Sub that is inside a while
   loop in Main.
2. The first time through the loop the files are created in the correct
   directory. the directory to write to (path) is passed to the Sub
   from the for each loop.
3. The paths and file names are       correct: I have written them with
   the immediate window and cut and pasted them into the file explorer.
   They are pointing to the right place.
4. When the create is hit, the file appears in the directory.
   When the end using is hit it vanishes. When the streamwriter object
   is created the file appears in the directory.  When it's end using
   is hit the file vanishes.

This is exactly the opposite problem from what most people have in where the fail to .close .flush .dispose or end using a stream writer.  Please also keep in mind that this code worked once.  And as fore mentioned works the first time through the loop.

Comment: Please put the code into the question so people don't have to click the link

Comment: I am sorry, this is not in a web app.  It is in a console app that is run nightly at 12:01 from the task scheduler on a Windows 2012 R2 Server.

Comment: `I don't think I actually need to create the file first.` - No you don't. The `StreamWriter` will create it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: This is a huge problem.  I am posting here because I can't find any information existing about this already on the inter web.  It would be awesome if someone can give me help or point me in the right direction as far as the real question is concerned: why is the file going away when the StreamWriter is closed, disposed or it's end using is hit?  As previously mentioned this code is called from inside a loop and the first time through the loop the StreamWriter does not delete the file when a close, dispose or it's end using are called.

Comment: Also, there is nothing that references the StreamWriter in any way that is run in the loop after the first time through all the StreamWriters.  That was one of the first things I checked.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out.  There was a service running on the server that was taking the files, as soon as they showed up, and FTPing them someplace and then deleting them when it was done.  Nobody bothered to tell me.